# Python xlsx conditional_format list not recognized

Tags: python, excel

I am using python to write a xls spreadsheet with conditional format

```
test = '=iferror(and(if({purch_qty}="",{needed_qty},{purch_qty})<{max_break},{cel}>lookup(if({purch_qty}="",{needed_qty},{purch_qty}),{{{qtys}}},{{{prices}}})),"")'.format(
                cel='M7',
                max_break='100',
                needed_qty='G7',
                purch_qty='K7',
                qtys='1,10,50',
                prices='1.3,6.8,16.9')
```

If I `print` this variable, the result is `=iferror(and(if(K7="",G7,K7)<100,M7>lookup(if(K7="",G7,K7),{1,10,50},{1.3,6.8,16.9})),"")`
, but inside excel/libreoffice happens an "interpretation error" and my formula is seen as `IFERROR(AND(IF(K7="";G7;K7)<100;M7>LOOKUP(IF(K7="";G7;K7);#NAME?;#NAME?));"")`.

Because of my language dot and comma is changed, but is not (directly) the issue.

What happens is the not correct interpretation of the `{}`'s internal part. If I type this manually (changing dot and comma) in the spreadsheet `IFERROR(AND(IF(K7="";G7;K7)<100;M7>LOOKUP(IF(K7="";G7;K7);{1.10.50};{1,3.6,8.16,9}));"")` works fine. Some one knows why? Is it related with my system language?

Comment: You haven't told us how you are creating the file. There are many ways that Python could be used. We can't tell from what you have shown us.

Comment: I was using the Xlsxwrite python library that was made to be used with Excel and I just realize today that Excel to not accept array inside the conditional format (LibreOffice Calc, yes).
So, this library (I contact the develop tam support in GitHub) do not have this feature because that is not compatible with Excel.